# ValueError: read of closed file while trying to convert .avro to .csv using Dask

Tags: python, dask

```
import dask.bag as db



class Converter():

    def __init__(self,input,output):
        """Converter constructor"""
        self.input = input
        self.output = output

    @staticmethod
    def large_file_reader(file_path: str):
        """
        File reader
        """
        temp_data = db.read_avro(file_path)
        data = temp_data.to_dataframe()
        # just to check able to by read properly 
        print(data.head(6))
        return data


    @staticmethod
    def large_file_writer(data, file_path: str) -> bool:
        """
        File writer
        """
        data.compute().to_csv(file_path, index=False)


    def large_file_processor(self):
        "Read  then write"
        input_file_path =self.input
        output_file_path =self.output
        data = Converter.large_file_reader(input_file_path)
        Converter.large_file_writer(data=data, file_path=output_file_path)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = Converter("/Users/csv_to_avro_new.avro", "/Users/test_avro_new.csv")
    c.large_file_processor()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/ms--py/new.py", line 41, in <module>
    c.large_file_processor()
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/ms--py/new.py", line 36, in large_file_processor
    Converter.large_file_writer(data=data, file_path=output_file_path)
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/ms--py/new.py", line 28, in large_file_writer
    data.compute().to_csv(file_path, index=False)
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/data-ingest/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 315, in compute
    (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/data-ingest/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 600, in compute
    results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/data-ingest/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/threaded.py", line 89, in get
    results = get_async(
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/data-ingest/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 511, in get_async
    raise_exception(exc, tb)
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/data-ingest/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 319, in reraise
    raise exc
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/data-ingest/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 224, in execute_task
    result = _execute_task(task, data)
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/data-ingest/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 119, in _execute_task
    return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/data-ingest/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 119, in <genexpr>
    return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
  File "/Users/adavsandeep/PycharmProjects/data-ingest/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 119, in _execute_task
    return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/data-ingest/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/bag/avro.py", line 150, in read_chunk
    chunk = read_block(f, off, l, head["sync"])
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/data-ingest/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fsspec/utils.py", line 244, in read_block
    found_start_delim = seek_delimiter(f, delimiter, 2**16)
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/data-ingest/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fsspec/utils.py", line 187, in seek_delimiter
    current = file.read(blocksize)
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/data-ingest/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fsspec/implementations/local.py", line 337, in read
    return self.f.read(*args, **kwargs)
ValueError: read of closed file

Process finished with exit code 1
```

`Added the error traceback.check it once.Thanks.

## Error

**ValueError: read of closed file**

Tried convert to some other formats like csv to json in the same way it was working
But not able to convert avro to csv, avro to json and avro to parquet

My file size is more than 2GB .Thats the reason I am using dask.
Thanks in advance .

`

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question and add the whole error traceback message.

Comment: @JohnGordon check the traceback